# html gif has transparent background but gets white in img tag and css background attribute

Tags: html, css, gif

I have a gif image with transparent background as you can see here in my desktop:

[image]

But when i use it in my html code, gets white background.
I have tested both background css attribute and replies in stackoverflow and other sites at google top pages.
here is my codes:

```
<img src="/content/elecomp98/pahbad.gif" style="position: absolute;top: 50px;left: 0;width: 250px;">

<div style="width: 250px;height: 280px;background: url(/content/elecomp98/pahbad.gif);position: absolute;left: 0;top: 50px;background-size: cover;display: none;"></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). **We'll need the ACTUAL image**.

Comment: of course. but its simple issue and there is no other detailed info.

Comment: I've added another image that shows problem more clear.

Comment: No...we need the **actual** image so we can reproduce the problem. *Images* of the problem are of little value.

Comment: Does the new image express the problem correctly?

Comment: It shows the problem but if we can't **reproduce it** then it's of little value. That's why we need the **actual** GIF to test.

Comment: Also note that "Pahbad.gif" is not the same as "pahbad.gif".

Comment: @MahdiRezaei provide the actual url of your image(not one relative to your file). If possible, upload your image somewhere and provide that link

Comment: @Paulie_D It was weird as I never seen characters case sensitive in web codes and urls.

Comment: @Paulie_D You saved my days. Add this answer, so I can confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "`Pahbad.gif`" is not the same as "`pahbad.gif`".

Image urls are **case-sensitive**.

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is not case sensitve. However, font families, URLs to images, and other direct references with the style sheet may be.

I would suggest that you are linking the wrong image.

Comment: your sentence "Image urls are case-sensitive." is totally FALSE. Image like all URLS ARE NOT case sensitive* *unless dynamically generated based on URL param, which not count on this example use case